# Undefined index error while saving dynamic generated table using multidimesnional array name to controls

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

i have generated html code dynamically through javascript

[image]

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Date </label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control hasDatepicker" name="ratedate" data-inputmask="'alias': 'dd/mm/yyyy'" data-mask="" id="datepicker" value="13/07/2016">
    </div>
    <!-- /.input group -->
</div>
<div class=" form-group">
    <label>Select Broker</label>

    <select class="products form-control" name="broker">
        <option value="0">-----Select Broker-----</option>
        <option value="1">ARIHANT ENTERPRISES</option>
        <option value="3">MEETA ENTERPRISES</option>
        <option value="2">VINAYAKA AGRO</option>
    </select>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
    <img src="../ajax-loader.gif" id="loding3" style="display: none;">

    <div class="productlist form-group">



        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function addRowToTable() {
                var tbl = document.getElementById('tblProducts');
                var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
                // if there's no header row in the table, then iteration = lastRow + 1
                var iteration = lastRow;
                var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);



                // product cell
                var cellRightSel = row.insertCell(0);
                var sel = document.createElement('select');
                sel.options[0] = new Option("BLACK SUNFLOWER SEED", "9");
                sel.options[1] = new Option("NIGER SEED", "11");
                sel.options[2] = new Option("SAFFLOWER SEED", "12");
                sel.options[3] = new Option("STRIP SUNFLOWER SEED", "10");
                sel.options[4] = new Option("YELLOW MILLET", "17");
                sel.options[5] = new Option("YELLOW SORGHUM", "19");
                sel.name = 'rates[products][]';
                sel.className = 'form-control';
                cellRightSel.appendChild(sel);




                // state cell
                var cellRightstate = row.insertCell(1);
                var state = document.createElement('select');
                state.name = 'rates[state][]';
                state.className = 'form-control';
                state.options[0] = new Option('--Select Origin--', '0');
                state.options[1] = new Option("Andaman and Nicobar Islands", "1");
                state.options[2] = new Option("Andhra Pradesh", "2");
                state.options[3] = new Option("Arunachal Pradesh", "3");
                state.options[4] = new Option("Assam", "4");
                state.options[5] = new Option("Bihar", "5");
                state.options[6] = new Option("Chandigarh", "6");
                state.options[7] = new Option("Chhattisgarh", "7");
                state.options[8] = new Option("Dadra and Nagar Haveli", "8");
                state.options[9] = new Option("Daman and Diu", "9");
                state.options[10] = new Option("Delhi", "10");
                state.options[11] = new Option("Goa", "11");
                state.options[12] = new Option("Gujarat", "12");
                state.options[13] = new Option("Haryana", "13");
                state.options[14] = new Option("Himachal Pradesh", "14");
                state.options[15] = new Option("Jammu and Kashmir", "15");
                state.options[16] = new Option("Jharkhand", "16");
                state.options[17] = new Option("Karnataka", "17");
                state.options[18] = new Option("Kenmore", "18");
                state.options[19] = new Option("Kerala", "19");
                state.options[20] = new Option("Lakshadweep", "20");
                state.options[21] = new Option("Madhya Pradesh", "21");
                state.options[22] = new Option("Maharashtra", "22");
                state.options[23] = new Option("Manipur", "23");
                state.options[24] = new Option("Meghalaya", "24");
                state.options[25] = new Option("Mizoram", "25");
                state.options[26] = new Option("Nagaland", "26");
                state.options[27] = new Option("Odisha", "29");
                state.options[28] = new Option("Paschim Medinipur", "30");
                state.options[29] = new Option("Pondicherry", "31");
                state.options[30] = new Option("Punjab", "32");
                state.options[31] = new Option("Rajasthan", "33");
                state.options[32] = new Option("Sikkim", "34");
                state.options[33] = new Option("Tamil Nadu", "35");
                state.options[34] = new Option("Telangana", "36");
                state.options[35] = new Option("Tripura", "37");
                state.options[36] = new Option("Uttar Pradesh", "38");
                state.options[37] = new Option("Uttarakhand", "39");
                state.options[38] = new Option("West Bengal", "41");
                cellRightstate.appendChild(state);




                // grade cell
                var cellRightgrade = row.insertCell(2);
                var grade = document.createElement('select');
                grade.name = 'rates[grade][]';
                grade.className = 'form-control';
                grade.options[0] = new Option('FD', 'FD');
                grade.options[1] = new Option('Chalna', 'Chalna');
                grade.options[2] = new Option('M.Clean', 'mc');
                grade.options[3] = new Option('Sortex', 'Sortex');
                grade.selectedIndex = 2;
                cellRightgrade.appendChild(grade);

                // pkg cell
                var cellRightpkg = row.insertCell(3);
                var pkg = document.createElement('select');
                pkg.name = 'rates[pkg][]';
                pkg.className = 'form-control';
                pkg.options[0] = new Option('5 kg', '5');
                pkg.options[1] = new Option('10 kg', '10');
                pkg.options[2] = new Option('20 kg', '20');
                pkg.options[3] = new Option('25 kg', '25');
                pkg.options[4] = new Option('50 kg', '50');
                pkg.options[5] = new Option('75 kg', '75');
                pkg.options[6] = new Option('80 kg', '80');
                pkg.options[6] = new Option('100 kg', '100');
                pkg.selectedIndex = 4;
                cellRightpkg.appendChild(pkg);

                // pkgtype cell
                var cellRightpkgtype = row.insertCell(4);
                var pkgtype = document.createElement('select');
                pkgtype.name = 'rates[pkgtype][]';
                pkgtype.className = 'form-control';
                pkgtype.options[0] = new Option('New PP Bag', 'New PP Bag');
                pkgtype.options[1] = new Option('Second PP Bag', 'Second PP Bag');
                pkgtype.options[2] = new Option('Jute Bag', 'Jute Bag');
                pkgtype.options[3] = new Option('Paper Bag', 'Paper Bag');
                cellRightpkgtype.appendChild(pkgtype);



                // paymode cell
                var cellRightpaymode = row.insertCell(5);
                var paymode = document.createElement('select');
                paymode.options[0] = new Option("1% CD", "1");
                paymode.options[1] = new Option("2% CD", "2");
                paymode.options[2] = new Option("2.5% CD", "3");
                paymode.options[3] = new Option("ADVANCE", "4");
                paymode.options[4] = new Option("10-12 DAYS", "5");
                paymode.name = 'rates[cd][]';
                paymode.className = 'form-control';
                cellRightpaymode.appendChild(paymode);

                // deltime cell
                var cellRightdeltime = row.insertCell(6);
                var deltime = document.createElement('select');
                deltime.name = 'rates[deltime][]';
                deltime.className = 'form-control';

                deltime.options[0] = new Option('JAN', '01');
                deltime.options[1] = new Option('FEB', '02');
                deltime.options[2] = new Option('MAR', '03');
                deltime.options[3] = new Option('APR', '04');
                deltime.options[4] = new Option('MAY', '05');
                deltime.options[5] = new Option('JUN', '06');
                deltime.options[6] = new Option('JUL', '07');
                deltime.options[7] = new Option('AUG', '08');
                deltime.options[8] = new Option('SEP', '09');
                deltime.options[9] = new Option('OCT', '10');
                deltime.options[10] = new Option('NOV', '11');
                deltime.options[11] = new Option('DEC', '12');
                deltime.selectedIndex = 6;
                cellRightdeltime.appendChild(deltime);



                // Delivery cell
                var cellRightdelivery = row.insertCell(7);
                var delivery = document.createElement('select');
                delivery.name = 'rates[del][]';
                delivery.className = 'form-control';
                delivery.options[0] = new Option('Mumbai', 'Mumbai');
                delivery.options[1] = new Option('Nagpur', 'Nagpur');
                delivery.options[2] = new Option('Mundra', 'Mundra');
                delivery.options[3] = new Option('Tuticorin', 'Tuticorin');
                delivery.options[3] = new Option('Kolkata', 'Kolkata');
                delivery.selectedIndex = 0;
                cellRightdelivery.appendChild(delivery);


                // Rate cell
                var cellRightrate = row.insertCell(8);
                var rate = document.createElement('input');
                rate.type = 'text';
                rate.name = 'rates[val][]';
                rate.className = 'form-control';
                rate.onkeypress = validate;
                rate.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Enter Rate');

                cellRightrate.appendChild(rate);

            }

            function removeRowFromTable() {
                var tbl = document.getElementById('tblProducts');
                var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
                if (lastRow > 2) tbl.deleteRow(lastRow - 1);
            }
        </script>

        <div class="box-body">

            <table class="table table-bordered" id="tblProducts">
                <thead>
                    <tr>

                        <th>Product</th>
                        <th>Origin</th>
                        <th>Grade</th>
                        <th>Packing</th>
                        <th>Pkg Type</th>

                        <th>Payment</th>
                        <th>Del. time</th>
                        <th>Del. Place</th>
                        <th>Rate</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <select class="state form-control" name="rates[products][]" disabled="disabled">
                                <option>--Select Product--</option>
                                <option value="28">BLACK CUMIN SEED</option>
                                <option value="16">BLACK MUSTARD SEED</option>
                                <option value="7">BLACK SESAME SEED - 99.1.1</option>
                                <option value="9" selected="">BLACK SUNFLOWER SEED</option>
                                <option value="31">CASSIA TORA</option>
                                <option value="29">CORIANDER SEEDS - EAGLE QUALITY</option>
                                <option value="33">CORIANDER SEEDS - PARROT QUALITY</option>
                                <option value="32">CORIANDER SEEDS - SCOOTER QUALITY</option>
                                <option value="22">CREAMISH SORGHUM</option>
                                <option value="27">CUMIN SEED - SINGAPORE QUALITY</option>
                                <option value="34">CUMIN SEEDS - EUROPE QUALITY</option>
                                <option value="30">FENNEL SEED</option>
                                <option value="26">GREEN MILLET</option>
                                <option value="23">GREY MILLET/JAP MILLET</option>
                                <option value="4">HULLED SESAME SEED - 99.90%</option>
                                <option value="3">HULLED SESAME SEED - 99.95%</option>
                                <option value="2">HULLED SESAME SEED - 99.97%</option>
                                <option value="1">HULLED SESAME SEED - 99.98%</option>
                                <option value="8">JET BLACK SESAME SEED - SORTEX</option>
                                <option value="13">LINSEED</option>
                                <option value="5">NATURAL SESAME SEED - 99.1.1</option>
                                <option value="6">NATURAL SESAME SEED - SORTEX</option>
                                <option value="11">NIGER SEED</option>
                                <option value="24">NORMAL MAIZE/CORN</option>
                                <option value="18">RED MILLET</option>
                                <option value="21">RED SORGHUM</option>
                                <option value="12">SAFFLOWER SEED</option>
                                <option value="25">SMALL YELLOW MAIZE</option>
                                <option value="14">SOYABEAN</option>
                                <option value="10">STRIP SUNFLOWER SEED</option>
                                <option value="20">WHITE SORGHUM</option>
                                <option value="17">YELLOW MILLET</option>
                                <option value="15">YELLOW MUSTARD SEED</option>
                                <option value="19">YELLOW SORGHUM</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="rates[state][]" class="form-control">
                                <option value="0">--Select Origin--</option>
                                <option value="1">Andaman and Nicobar Islands</option>
                                <option value="2">Andhra Pradesh</option>
                                <option value="3">Arunachal Pradesh</option>
                                <option value="4">Assam</option>
                                <option value="5">Bihar</option>
                                <option value="6">Chandigarh</option>
                                <option value="7">Chhattisgarh</option>
                                <option value="8">Dadra and Nagar Haveli</option>
                                <option value="9">Daman and Diu</option>
                                <option value="10">Delhi</option>
                                <option value="11">Goa</option>
                                <option value="12">Gujarat</option>
                                <option value="13">Haryana</option>
                                <option value="14">Himachal Pradesh</option>
                                <option value="15">Jammu and Kashmir</option>
                                <option value="16">Jharkhand</option>
                                <option value="17">Karnataka</option>
                                <option value="18">Kenmore</option>
                                <option value="19">Kerala</option>
                                <option value="20">Lakshadweep</option>
                                <option value="21">Madhya Pradesh</option>
                                <option value="22">Maharashtra</option>
                                <option value="23">Manipur</option>
                                <option value="24">Meghalaya</option>
                                <option value="25">Mizoram</option>
                                <option value="26">Nagaland</option>
                                <option value="29">Odisha</option>
                                <option value="30">Paschim Medinipur</option>
                                <option value="31">Pondicherry</option>
                                <option value="32">Punjab</option>
                                <option value="33">Rajasthan</option>
                                <option value="34">Sikkim</option>
                                <option value="35">Tamil Nadu</option>
                                <option value="36">Telangana</option>
                                <option value="37">Tripura</option>
                                <option value="38">Uttar Pradesh</option>
                                <option value="39">Uttarakhand</option>
                                <option value="41">West Bengal</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="rates[grade][]" class="form-control">
                                <option value="FD">FD</option>
                                <option value="Chalna">Chalna</option>
                                <option value="mc" selected="selected">M.Clean</option>

                                <option value="Sortex">Sortex</option>


                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="rates[pkg][]" class="form-control">
                                <option value="5">5 kg</option>
                                <option value="10">10 kg</option>
                                <option value="20">20 kg</option>
                                <option value="25">25 kg</option>
                                <option value="50" selected="selected">50 kg</option>
                                <option value="75">75 kg</option>
                                <option value="80">80 kg</option>
                                <option value="100">100 kg</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="rates[pkgtype][]" class="form-control">
                                <option value="New PP Bag" selected="selected">New PP Bag</option>
                                <option value="Second PP Bag">Second PP Bag</option>
                                <option value="Jute Bag">Jute Bag</option>
                                <option value="Paper Bag">Paper Bag</option>

                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="rates[cd][]" class="form-control">
                                <option value="1">1% CD</option>
                                <option value="2">2% CD</option>
                                <option value="3">2.5% CD</option>
                                <option value="4">ADVANCE</option>
                                <option value="5">10-12 DAYS</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="rates[deltime][]" class="form-control">

                                <option value="1">JAN</option>
                                <option value="2">FEB</option>
                                <option value="3">MAR</option>
                                <option value="4">APR</option>
                                <option value="5">MAY</option>
                                <option value="6">JUN</option>
                                <option value="7" selected="">JUL</option>
                                <option value="8">AUG</option>
                                <option value="9">SEP</option>
                                <option value="1">OCT</option>
                                <option value="11">NOV</option>
                                <option value="12">DEC</option>



                            </select>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <select name="rates[del][]" class="form-control">
                                <option value="Mumbai" selected="selected">Mumbai</option>
                                <option value="Nagpur">Nagpur</option>
                                <option value="Mundra">Mundra</option>
                                <option value="Tuticorin">Tuticorin</option>
                                <option value="Kolkata">Kolkata</option>

                            </select>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" required="" placeholder="Enter Rate" name="rates[val][]" onKeyPress="validate(event)">
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div style="width:200px;margin-right:25px;float:left">
                <input type="button" value="Add Product" class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-flat" onClick="addRowToTable();">
            </div>
            <div style="width:200px;float:left;">
                <input type="button" value="Remove Product" class="btn btn-block btn-danger btn-flat" onClick="removeRowFromTable();">
            </div>




        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-lg" name="send" value="Submit" type="submit" onClick="validateRow(this.form);">Submit</button>
<!-- textarea -->
<!-- input states -->
<!-- checkbox -->
<!-- radio -->
<!-- select -->
<!-- Select multiple-->
```

i have below code written to save the values

```
        $numFields = count($_POST['rates']['products']);

        for ($i = 0; $i < $numFields; $i++) 
        {

            // Pack the field up in an array for ease-of-use.
            $field = array(
                'products' => $_POST['rates']['products'][$i],
                'state' => $_POST['rates']['state'][$i],
                'grade' => $_POST['rates']['grade'][$i],
                'pkg' => $_POST['rates']['pkg'][$i],
                'pkgtype' => $_POST['rates']['pkgtype'][$i],
                'cd' => $_POST['rates']['cd'][$i],
                'deltime' => $_POST['rates']['deltime'][$i],
                'del' => $_POST['rates']['del'][$i],
                'val' => $_POST['rates']['val'][$i]);   


                  $insert=mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO `daily_rates`(`broker_id`, `product_id`,`state`, `grade`, `packing`, `packing_type`, `payment_mode`, `del_time`, `del_place`, `rates`,`rate_date`) VALUES ('$brokerid',".$field['products'].",".$field['state'].",,'".$field['grade']."','".$field['pkg']."','".$field['pkgtype']."',".$field['cd'].",'".$field['deltime']."','".$field['del']."',".$field['val'].",'".$pricedate."')");
```

but this code is giving me the error

> undefined index "products" in $numFields = $_POST['rates']['products'];

Comment: Have you tried print_r($_POST['rates']) first? Check which values you're getting.

Comment: kindly post html as plain text (code) please.

Comment: your product select element appears to be disabled, in which case it won't post to the server

Comment: Dear J.Chomel , find requested html

Comment: Thanks @billyonecan it works... Many thanks....

Answer (score 0):

product select element appears to be disabled, in which case it won't post to the server given by -  @billyonecan